# right clicking "Open Terminal" in Nautilus opens a terminal in the background

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 22.10

right clicking "Open Terminal" in Nautilus opens a terminal in the background, meaning I have to click on the Terminal application in the docking area to be able to use it. This didn't used to happen.

I am using Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: `sudo apt reinstall nautilus`